# How can you modify the plot of a series?

Tags: pine-script

I'm plotting values using the script below. How can I update it so the series is an arbitrary amount bigger? I don't want to change the len, just make it wider by say 50 points.

Thank you,

M

```
//@version=4
study("Linear Regression Channel",shorttitle="LRC_SH",overlay=true)
len = input(300,title="Length")

smoothLen = 50
upper = sma(high, smoothLen) 
lower = sma(low,smoothLen)

a = linreg(upper,len,0)
b = linreg(lower,len,0)
c = -dev(low,len)+b
d = dev(high,len)+a //test 

//plot(a) //middle line
//plot(b) //middle line
plot(c,color=c>c[1]? color.green:color.red)
plot(d,color=d>d[1]? color.green:color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. One way to do it is:

```
theHigh = high
theLow = low


float coeff =.005
theHigh := high + (coeff * high)
theLow  := low  - (coeff * low)
```